# How to set runtime environment variables for dockerized react app

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

For a react app with **.env**:

```
REACT_APP_ENV_VAR_1=A
REACT_APP_ENV_VAR_2=B
```

Customizing an environnement variable through **docker-compose.yml** doesn't alter its default value:

```
services:
  front:
    image: "react-app-image"
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_ENV_VAR_2=C
```

**.env** variable could be used in the react app:

```
let env_var_2 = process.env.REACT_APP_ENV_VAR_2;
```

Is there a way to directly access docker-compose ENV from react app or to map .env entries with docker ENV ?

---

Front **Dockerfile** for building react app image

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./

RUN npm ci --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Environment variables are applied at *build time*. Does the start script of the container build the project or does it just serve already an already built bundle?

Comment: The startup script recreate the project at each run `docker-compose up -d --force-recreate`, the front service (react app) in docker-compose use a docker image built independently of docker-compose

Comment: For python, using `os.getenv('ENV_VAR_2', 'B')` does the trick same as `${ENV_VAR_2:B}` in application.yml for java spring application, problem persists for react apps

Comment: Could you please show your Dockerfile for the frontend?

Comment: Sure, adding it on the question